# Update MySQL table using Text Boxes and Edit Button (using HTML and PHP)

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm working on a page that adds a category to a Category table. I got the Insert (Add New Category) feature to work, but my Update feature isn't updating the value. I've seen other questions similar that I have worked with, but it doesn't seem to solve my issue, one that I can't identify specifically other than the Update feature isn't working.

I suspected my Update query, but I believe it is correct. So I am stumped and looking for another person to see if they catch something.

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>Current Categories:</h1>

<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("hidden","hidden","hidden","hidden");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Category WHERE Class_idClass = 1";

//WHERE $_SESSION['user'] = 

$result = mysqli_query($con,$strSQL);
?>

<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Category</th>
<th>Weight</th>
<th>Category Type</th>
<th>Est. # of Assignments</th>
</tr>


<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
?>

<tr>
<td>
<input type="text" name="CategoryTitle" size="20" value="<?php echo $row['CategoryTitle']; ?>">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="CategoryWeight" size="20" value="<?php echo $row['CategoryWeight']; ?>" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)">
</td>
<td>
<select id="CategoryType" name="CategoryType">
         <option value="<?php echo $row['CategoryType']; ?>" selected='selected'>Current: <?php echo $row['CategoryType']; ?></option>
            <option value="T">Test (T)</option>
            <option value="H">Homework (H)</option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>   
</select>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="CategoryAssignmentEstimates" value="<?php echo $row['CategoryAssignmentEstimates']; ?>" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)">
</td>

<td>
<?php
$iduser=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$rows['idUser']);
echo "<input name='Edit' type='submit' id='Edit' value='Edit'></td>";
 ?>
</td>

</tr>
<?php
 }
?>
</table>

<?php
mysqli_close($con);
?>



<form action="insertCategory.php" method="post">
<br>
New Category Name: <input type="text" name="CategoryTitle"><br>
Weight Percentage: <input type="text" name="CategoryWeight" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"><br>
Category Type:
<select id="CategoryType" name="CategoryType"> 
            <option value="T">Exam/Test</option>
            <option value="H">Homework</option>
            <option value="">Other</option>   
</select><br>
Estimated Number of Assignments: <input type="text" name="CategoryAssignmentEstimates" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)">

<?php
$ClassID = '1';
$CatClassID = $_POST['$ClassID'];
?>

<script language="javascript">
function isNumber(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="Add">
</form>

<?php
//If edit was hit
if ($_POST['edit']) {
    $CatTitle = $_POST['CategoryTitle'];
    $CatWeight= $_POST['CategoryWeight'];
    $CatType = $_POST['CategoryType'];
    $CatEstNumAssign= $_POST['CategoryAssignmentEstimates'];

$query="UPDATE Category SET CategoryTitle = '$CatTitle', CategoryWeight = '$CatWeight', CategoryType = '$CatType', CategoryAssignmentEstimates = '$CatEstNumAssign' WHERE Class_idClass = 1";
//Below didn't work with period and quotes
//$query="UPDATE Category SET CategoryTitle = '".$CatTitle."', CategoryWeight = '".$CatWeight."', CategoryType = '".$CatType."', CategoryAssignmentEstimates = '".$CatEstNumAssign."' WHERE Class_idClass = 1";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
}

// Insert data
//if ($_POST['Add']) {
//  $Insert = mysql_query("INSERT Category SET CategoryTitle = '$CatTitle', CategoryWeight = '$CatWeight', CategoryType = '$CatType', CategoryAssignmentEstimates = '$CatEstNumAssign', Class_idClass = 1") 
//  or die ('Error Updating Data! <br />' .mysql_error());

//  echo 'Update successful';
//}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What happens when you click 'Edit'?

Comment: I don't get errors. Nothing happens. I tried changing the Edit button from type=button to type=submit, but it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Edit` submit button and inputs are not inside a form. When you hit `Edit` nothing happens because the button is not a part of a form so it does not submit anything. Try wrapping all the edit options with

```
<form action="" method="post">

    <input type="text" ... >
    <input type="text" ... >

    <select> ... </select> 

    ....

    <input type="submit" ... >

</form>
```

Note that the `action=""` will submit the form to the current page.

Comment: But the insertCategory.php is a separate file to run the Insert query, where I'm trying to run the Update query on the page. Do I still want to put the form around it even if it is for the Insert new category feature?

Comment: Sorry I just assumed `insertCategory.php` was the processing page. You still need a form, but if you want it to simply submit to itself (the page the form is on), then just use `<form action="" method="post">`. An empty action will default to the current page. See my updated answer.

Comment: Could I put the entire section in the form? When I put the button in a form, it not only made my table look weird, but it didn't work, even after the refresh.

Comment: The entire section - all inputs and the submit button - *must* be in the form. You can start and end the form wherever you want, as long as it contains all input values and the submit button. Meaning, you can start the form outside the table or directly above the first input, just so long as all the data you are submitting is between `<form ...>` and `</form>`. I will update my answer to clarify.

Comment: You definitely helped. After submitting, unfortunately, the value just changes back to the original.